# a list of strings in Java

Tags: java

I have a question about setting the value to the list of strings in Java.

For example, if you have a list of strings called names, how would you set the 3rd name to the value "San Diego"?

I tried names.add(2, "San Diego") but it's not working.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Also, how would I print the 3rd item from a list called students?

Comment: Try to use `set` instead of `add` . To read it you can use `get(2)` .

Comment: It would depend on the container class, but it’s based `java.util.List`, then it’s `set`

Comment: Oh, add you should consult the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) first 

Comment: Please read [ask]. You are supposed to do proper research before asking a question at StackOverflow. This includes reading through the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of a class you are using. The documentation explains all of those methods in detail, and gives examples. Alternatively, you can also search on google and probably find a lot of tutorials and examples on how to use `List`. Likely, this is also the reason for the down-votes.

Answer (score 2):

To update the already existing value use `names.set(2,"String");`

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you, sir. If I want to print the 3rd item from the student list. Can I do  System.out.printIn(students.indexOf(2))?

Comment: use students.get(2);  indexOf method will return the index of the object that you pass as the argument if the object is present in the list students. e.g names.indexOf ("San Diego") will return 2 in your case

Answer (score 2):

`names.add(2, "San Diego")` will add a new element at the 3rd position (index 2), but it will only work if the `List` already contains at least 2 elements.

`names.set(2, "San Diego")` will set the 3rd element (at index 2) to the required value, but it will work only if the `List` already contains at least 3 elements.

To obtain the 3rd element, you should use `names.get(2)` (again, the `List` must contain at least 3 elements for this to work).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace an existing item in a list, you have to use `set` instead of `add`

```
names.set(2,"San Diego");
```

In here **2** means the index, counting from 0.
Then is the String you want to add

If you want to read values from the list you can use `get`

```
String value = names.get(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

it will work if the List already contains at least 2 elements.

```
names.add(2, "San Diego") it will override the 3rd element or at index 2.
```

it is always safe to use

```
names.set(2, "San Diego") it will set the 3rd value or at index 2 if the list contains at least 3 elements.
```

Otherwise, it will throw IndexOutOfBoundsException:  exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basic operation you can perform there are plenty of operation you can perform.
One advice try try and try dont give up.
here the is link for java dock for your reference
[Java doc for List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```js
package com.varun.list;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayListTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Create array list
    List < String > names = new ArrayList < String > ();

    //Create few names
    String sam = "Sam";
    String jamie = "Jamie_dogLover";
    String bucy = "The Bucky";

    // add all names in the list
    names.add(sam);
    names.add(jamie);
    names.add(bucy);
    System.out.println("List values :" + names); //Output : List values :[Sam, Jamie_dogLover, The Bucky]

    //Update the second index that is -> The Bucky, because list index starts from 0 
    names.set(2, "New Bucky");
    System.out.println("New List values :" + names); //Output : New List values :[Sam, Jamie_dogLover, New Bucky]

    //Lest say you want to remove the the 1st index that is jamie
    names.remove(jamie);
    System.out.println("Updates List values :" + names); //Output : Updates List values :[Sam, New Bucky]

    //Let say you get a list of name from somewhere and you want to add into you existing list(names) 
    names.addAll(listOfDummyNames());

    System.out.println("Updates List values with dummy names :" + names);
    //Output : Updates List values with dummy names :[Sam, New Bucky, Name0, Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4]
    //Let say you want to to remove all the name who has "name" String in it

    Iterator < String > itr = names.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
      String name = itr.next();
      if (name.contains("Name")) {
        itr.remove();
      }
    }

    System.out.println("List after removing all name who has Name in it : " + names);

  }

  private static List < String > listOfDummyNames() {

    List < String > dummyList = new ArrayList < String > ();
    String name = "Name";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      dummyList.add(name + i);
    }

    System.out.println("List of dummy Names :" + dummyList);
    return dummyList;
  }

}
```